# Can not modify Primary Key field using an online SQL Table Editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have tried 2 different online sql table editors,

Universal Table Editor &
Table Smart Editor

When viewing the database using the tools above, if there is a primary key field defined in my tables, it is uneditable. At the beggining I was thinking that it was related to table editor, however 2 different editors resulted the same problem, so I am thinking it is related to sql server.

I am currently using SQL Server 2005.

Here are the images for my editors and my database properties:

[image: Table Smart Editor Screenshot for my table]

[image: Universal Table Editor Screenshot for my table]

[image: My database properties for my table]

[image: TSE Error image]

[image: UTE Error image]

Comment: Editing how? Changing the values of that column in particular rows, or changing the definition (type, size, etc) of the column?

Comment: Changing the values of the columns are not possible, I added screenshots of the editors, column editing is disabled for primary keys, please see my edited answer.

Comment: Possibly you seem right about it, but for example for an access database, the tools are working okey. My solution will be removing the primary key from 2 coluns, and add UNIQUE constraint instead for my columns. Please write your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editors you're using seem to have been built with certain assumptions - that primary key values never change, and furthermore that they're always system generated.

Neither assumption is *generally* true. Whilst it's often described as desirable that primary key values never change, a good tool should not assume this to be true. Nor should it assume that primary key values will always be auto-generated.

---

There are some mitigating features built into SQL to deal with primary keys that *do* change - notably, the `CASCADE` features of `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, an error message will accompany a failed attempt to modify a database value. What was the message?

This sounds like the primary key is set up as an auto-numbered identity. In this case, the value is determined by the database automatically when each row is created. And you cannot edit this value.

Comment: Well, there you go. The ID was NULL, which is not allowed. I can't tell exactly what you are doing but I see an INSERT query above that does not specify the value of the ID column. That means it's NULL. That means it's not allowed.

Comment: But autoincrement doesn't solve my problem, let's say there is a book (brothers karamazov is in database with id=5, copy=1) , and librarian recieved another copy of this book, he has to be able to insert id=5, copy=2 of the book to database.